# Extract pattern from filename using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string:

> "UNKNOWN_{_requestID___b9b6bcc4-c163-45d7-82d9-423a96cf5fe1_,_deviceID___9c84f871-9e95-45d5-9335-12e7d42b96a0_}_2018-08-15-15-43-01-296_529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6.txt"

and I want to extract the `529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6` part (the last part between _ and .txt).

Here is what I am trying to do using regex:

`^\_\w\.txt` but without luck, I am keep playing with this, please advise what is the strategy and how to "attack" this.

Comment: This question has sample data, expected output and attempts at solving the problem. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sub("^.*_(.*)\\.txt$", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LhX1py/1)

`sub` will perform a single seasrch and replace operation. It will find a match if the string conforms to the following:

- `^`  start of string
- `.*_` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last `_`
- `(.*)` - any 0+ chars (captured into Group 1,later referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern), as many as possible, up to and including...
- `\\.txt$`  - `.txt` (`.` must be escaped to match a literal dot) at the end of the string (`$`).

[R demo](https://ideone.com/cN3Ymh):

```
x <- "UNKNOWN_{_requestID___b9b6bcc4-c163-45d7-82d9-423a96cf5fe1_,_deviceID___9c84f871-9e95-45d5-9335-12e7d42b96a0_}_2018-08-15-15-43-01-296_529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6.txt"
sub("^.*_(.*)\\.txt$", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6"
```

Comment: Another base R way is to match the value, [`unlist(regmatches(x, regexec("([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\\.txt", x)))[2]`](https://ideone.com/AwVzal) or `regmatches(x, regexpr("[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=\\.txt)", x, perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's using a hidden gem from tools.

```
x <- "UNKNOWN_{_requestID___b9b6bcc4-c163-45d7-82d9-423a96cf5fe1_,_deviceID___9c84f871-9e95-45d5-9335-12e7d42b96a0_}_2018-08-15-15-43-01-296_529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6.txt"

out <- strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]
out <- out[length(out)]
tools::file_path_sans_ext(out)

[1] "529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6"
```

Comment: I like the creative solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
gsub(".*_|\\.txt","",x)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "529307b7-\n6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6"
```

***Explanation:*** Adding following only for explanation purposes.

```
gsub(     ##Using gsub(Global substitution function of R to perform multiple substitution on variables)
".*_      ##Mentioning REGEX to select everything from starting till _(underscore)
|         ##|(pipe) defines OR so it should match either previous or coing REGEX in varibale's value.
\\.txt"   ##\\. means escaping DOT so that DOT should be treated as a DOT not with its special meaning so it should match string .txt
,""       ##If above mentioned REGEXs any one of them OR both matches then substitute them with "" means NULL.
,x)       ##Mentioning variable named x on which we have to perform gsub.
```

Where Input variable `x`'s value is as follows.

```
x <- "UNKNOWN_{_requestID___b9b6bcc4-c163-45d7-82d9-423a96cf5fe1_,_deviceID
___9c84f871-9e95-45d5-9335-12e7d42b96a0_}_2018-08-15-15-43-01-296_529307b7-
6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

apply 2 times sub:

```
    text <- c("UNKNOWN_{_requestID___b9b6bcc4-c163-45d7-82d9-423a96cf5fe1_,_deviceID___9c84f871-9e95-45d5-9335-12e7d42b96a0_}_2018-08-15-15-43-01-296_529307b7-6316-4cdc-ab53-2e1158c651c6.txt" )
    sub("\\.txt.*", "", sub(".*\\_", "", text))
```

Comment: I believe for these purposes only we have `gsub` where you need not to use multiple times `sub`.